# Can someone debug a progress bar issue in my Javascript applet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, settimeout

[Here is the applet](http://jsfiddle.net/jrenfree/4msP6/)

You can leave all the settings as they are, then hit "Calculate".  After a few seconds, you should see some plots show up, then the progress bar below the "Calculate" button will fill up to 100%.

The problem is that I'd like the progress bar to increment while the code is running, not after it has completed as the plots are made.  I know the code is long, but you can search for the following progress bar code:

```
setTimeout( update(count++, L.length, f.length, phi.length) );
```

It accesses the function update(s,x,y,z) which is defined directly before the main calculate() function.

I'm just confused as to why the progress bar doesn't update until all the processing is complete.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you observe is caused by javascript's single-threaded nature. Timeouts do not get executed while existing code is being executed. Web workers were introduced to deal with just that type of restriction. If you are unable to use web workers(e.g. due to IE limitations), using timeouts is the only way to emulate multythreading.

To check that, you may replace your line with `update(count++, L.length, f.length, phi.length)()` and change `update` to log values into console.

As for current update implementation, I suppose either there are some any mini timers inside jquery, causing the issue, or browser rendering capabilities are just not available for some reason:).

<strike>The reason is that your calculations and drawings take far less time than timeout. Therefore by the time timeout functions are executed, everything has already been drawn.
You could verify that by replacing your line with `update(count++, L.length, f.length, phi.length)()` - it will lead to instant update up to 100%.</strike>

To get progress bar work more precise you should review your calculation code and try rewriting it in a chunk-friendly manner. I mean having a possibility to execute calculations chunk by chunk and updating progress bar at the end of each chunk. Having that done, you could use timer to evaluate everything.

Sample:

```
(function(){
    var arr = [1,2,3,4];
    (function popLog(){
        console.log(arr.pop());
        if (arr.length > 0){
            setTimeout(popLog, 100);
        }
    })();
})()
```

Another approach is using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers), querying the status from time to time and updating progress bar appropriately. However, IE does not support them.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow.  The calculations can take quite a while, as there are 3 for loops that loop through the range of lengths, frequencies, and angles.  For example, if you change the lengths to be from 200 to 210 mm, then the calculations should take about 20 seconds to complete.  I don't see how the timeout to update the progress bar can be slower than that.

Comment: My initial assumption seem to be incorrect - updated the answer. However, the cure remains the same - try using times/web workers for calculations.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I was under the assumptions that timeouts do get executed simultaneously as other code, so I guess what's happening is that the timeout isn't processing until all the calculations are done.  I need this to work in IE, so I'm guessing that I need to break this up into chunks and use multiple setTimeouts to control the order in which sections of the code get processed?  Thanks again, I really appreciate it

Comment: The main idea is to store current calculations state and have the ability to perform calculations based on that state. Than you could just set a 1msec timeout between evaluation steps and update the progress bar at the end of each.